# How to upgrade to CouchDB 1.3.0 + on CentOS 6?

Tags: linux, centos, couchdb, rpm, yum

I'm at my wits end trying to unravel all of the dependencies to compile CouchDB from source to run on CentOS 6.  Is there a pre-comiled package out there somewhere that will give me the latest version of CouchDB (currently 1.3.0)? My original install was accomplished using:

```
# yum install couchdb
```

... which results in a very old version 1.0.4!  I would think that there has to be another method to easily get the latest CouchDB installed.  Any suggestions other than compiling from source?

Answer (score 0):

I realise that this post is now old, but this may still help someone with this search;

I'm afraid I am not aware of any 1.3.0 releases pre-compiled into rpms, but here is a [download link](https://db.tt/8tPDaQs5) for a 1.4.0 rpm to be used under CentOS 6 (link found via [this page](https://dgunix.com/167-creating-self-contained-couchdb-rpms-for-centos6/)).

Once downloaded, use `rpm -ivh [filename]` to install the rpm.

Hope that helps.